# inline block elements are off position

Tags: html, css

Does any one know why my text keeps pushing my 1 block element down? When i remove the text, the block elements are perfectly inline with each other.

```
<div class="item-0" align="center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="body-0">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div><!-- body-0 -->

            <div class="image-0">
                <img src="images/ios_android_devices2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="ios_android" id="ios_android">
            </div><!-- image-0 -->

        </div><!-- col12 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- item-0 -->
```

CSS is as follows

```
.item-0 {
background-color: green;
```

}

```
.body-0{
display: inline-block;
background-color: red;
max-width: 100;
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
```

}

```
.image-0 {
display: inline-block;
height: 250px;
max-width: 100;
width: 300px;
background-color: #ccc;
```

}

Comment: Why are you using bootdtraps grid on some part of it? You could use col-lg-7 and 5 on each div and remove the lg-12 div and get the same result, if I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`vertical-align:top;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

```
   .image-0 {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 250px;
      max-width: 100;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: #ccc;
      vertical-align:top;
    }
    .body-0{
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: red;
      max-width: 100;
      width: 400px;
      height: 250px;
      vertical-align:top;
    }
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/pjGMMR)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align:top` to align the inline blocks with each other (note: use the "Full page" option in the demo to see the effect):

```css
.item-0 {
background-color: green;
}

.body-0{
display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
background-color: red;
max-width: 100;
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
}

.image-0 {
display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
height: 250px;
max-width: 100;
width: 300px;
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-0" align="center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="body-0">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div><!-- body-0 -->

            <div class="image-0">
                <img src="images/ios_android_devices2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="ios_android" id="ios_android">
            </div><!-- image-0 -->

        </div><!-- col12 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- item-0 -->
```